# Does a thesaurus of comparative adverbs or comparative adjectives exist? Needing a replacement for "more successful"

Tags: single-word-requests, resources

I want a word but I don't want to have to use "more successful". I don't consider successfuler a suitable attempt in the context I want to use it in either.

I think this is called a comparative adverb, but I don't know of a thesaurus of comparative adverbs. Can anyone point me to that?
Failing that, has anyone got ideas for an aspirational word that could replace "more successful"?

Comment: *successful* is not an adverb, it's an adjective. I suggest looking up a suitable synonym of this word in any dictionary online, and then simply use its comparative form.

Comment: The phrase "more successful" is what I am referring to as a comparative adverb. From a Google "define:comparative adverb" search
"comparative adverb - an adverb that compares two actions and is formed by adding –er to the end or more/less to the beginning of a regular adverb. http://rmfs1.ortn.edu/myschool/mcain/Web/Grammar Flashcards.mht"

Comment: I understand that you refer to "more successful" as a comparative adverb, but it is not, it is a comparative adjective.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that now @vilmar, thanks. I just feel too constrained at present by having to use "more" first - it's for a motto and it ruins the flow at the moment. The comparative forms of too many words seem to require it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Successful* is an adjective, while *succesfully* is the adverb form of it. Maybe a replacement for '*more successful*' could be '***of greater success***' or '***better/more achieved***'. If the context of 'successful' deals more with money and/or position, than also consider '***wealthier***', '***more aristocratic***', and '***better titled***'.

I'm probably not the best person to listen to for this though. Looking up synonyms for 'successful' on [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com) or any other website for yourself would be your best route.

Comment: Thanks Arturo. I'm looking for a one word replacement. Some words have a suitable "er" ending, such as safe->safer, but right now I've got successful->"more successful".